# How to add rewrite configuration on Azure Web Apps?

Tags: php, azure, mod-rewrite, iis, nginx

**Problem:**

I am trying to migrate a PHP web app from having its own VPS with nginx to be an Azure Web App. In the NGINX configuration, there are some rewrite rules that needs to be migrated too. Now the app is up and running except for the rewrites.

**What I did**

So to put the rewrites I created a file called `applicationHost.xdt` and added it to `/site` folder. I tested that the new `.xdt` is being read by adding a timeout rule, which I later foud that it has been inserted at main config file in `/local/Config/applicationhost.config`. However my rule is not there and it is not working at all.

I have also tried adding the below file under the name `web.config` in `/wwwroot` folder.

**applicationHost.xdt:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionTimeout)" 
               connectionTimeout="00:00:30" />
  </system.applicationHost>

  <location path="{main_location_for_web_app}" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" >

    <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" lockElements="clear">
          <rule name="amr" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" lockItem="true">
            <match url="{my app url}/introduction.php" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{my app url}/reset.php" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
      </location>

</configuration>
```

I am fairly new to all this but it is a task I need to do. I appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong or the best way to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this in `web.config` file under `/wwwroot` folder. This will redirect the user from `introduction.php` to `reset.php`. I tested it, it should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>    
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="amr" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" lockItem="true">
                    <match url="introduction.php" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="reset.php" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more details, please refer to [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

---

I also tried your `applicationHost.xdt` after changing the following line:

```
<location path="{main_location_for_web_app}" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" >
```

to:

```
<location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
```

and restarted the App Service, then I got it worked.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still trying to make it work. I used the sample you provided and instead of `introduction.php` I used `.*` put neither worked for me. What is the best way to debug it ? how can I be 100% certain that the `web.config` file is getting read. Thanks again.

Comment: found my error. My code was in `/wwwroot/html` not `/wwwroot` so the `web.config` file needed to be in `/wwwroot/html/` as it is the new root of the web app.